# A cleaner way to query a collection and return the data as a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

It seems like there is a cleaner and more optimised way to query a Firestore collection, call `doc.data()` on each doc, and then return an array as result. The order in which the docs are pushed into the result array *feels* haphazard.

There are many steps to this code:

1. A new `result` variable is created
2. A query is made to retrieve the 'stories' collection
3. For each doc, we call the `doc.data()`
4. We push each doc to the `result` array
5. Return the `result` array

```
  function getStories() {
    var result = [];
    db.collection('stories').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => result.push(doc.data()));
    })
    return result;
  }
```

The code works fine but it seems like we can write this code in a cleaner way with less steps.

Comment: can you give an example data of both input and the desired output you would like to achieve..

Comment: I am afraid if you are getting the desired behavior. This should return empty array always

Answer (score 0):

First, define a `map` function for use with firebase (named `mapSnapshot` because it is meant specifically for use with firebase):

```
const mapSnapshot = f => snapshot => {
  const r = [];
  snapshot.forEach(x => { r.push(f(x)); });
  return r;
}
```

Then, you can just work with `Promise` and `mapSnapshot`:

```
function getStories() {
  return db.collection('stories').
    get().
    then(mapSnapshot(doc => doc.data()));
}
```

Usage example:

```
getStories().then(docs => ... do whatever with docs ...)
```

To be honest, it isn't *less code* if used as a one-time solution. But the neat thing here is, it allows to create *reusable abstractions*. So for example, you could use `mapSnapshot` to create a `snapshotToArray` function which can be reused whenever you need to convert the DataSnapshot from firebase to a normal `Array`:

```
const snapshotToArray = mapSnapshot(x => x);
```

Please note: This *doesn't depend on any collection name whatsoever*. You can use it with *any* DataSnapshot from *any* collection to convert it into an `Array`!

That's not all. You can just as easily create a function from the contents of a DataSnapshot into a regular `Array` with the contents in it:

```
const readDocsData = mapSnapshot(x => x.data());
```

Again, this doesn't look like a big deal – until you realize, you can also create a `fromFirebase` function, which allows to query various datasets:

```
const fromFirebase = (name, transform = x => x) => {
  return db.collection(name).get().then(transform);
}
```

And which you can then use like this:

```
fromFirebase('stories', readDocsData).then(docs => {
  // do what you want to do with docs
});
```

This way, the final result has less steps you as a programmer notice immediatly. But it produced (although reusable) several intermediate steps, each hiding a bit of abstraction.

Comment: querySnapshot does not have a `map` function

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared actually doesn't work, as George comment. Since Firestore loads data asynchronously, you're always returns the array before the data has been loaded. So your array will be empty.

In code:

```
function getStories() {
  var result = [];
  db.collection('stories').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => result.push(doc.data()));
  })
  return result;
}
var result = getStories();
console.log(result.length);
```

Will log:

> 0

To fix this, you want to return a promise, which resolves once the data has loaded. Something along these lines:

```
function getStories() {
  var result = [];
  return db.collection('stories').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => result.push(doc.data()));
    return result;
  })
}
```

So this basically added two return statements, which makes your `result` bubble up and then be returned as the promise from `getStories`. To invoke this, you'd do:

```
getStories().then(result => {
  console.log(result.length);
})
```

Which will then log the correct number of results.